# cloud foundry postgres service memory usage

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a postgres service in cloud foundry connected to my application. I want to know how to check memory size of postgres service. Could someone guide me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry does not have that information, so there's no direct way to get it from a `cf` cli command.

When you create a service instance, the Cloud Controller talks using the [Open Service Broker API](https://www.openservicebrokerapi.org/) to a service broker. The broker will then create the actual database or service itself, outside of Cloud Foundry. It might spin up a VM, it might spin up a full cluster, it might just add a DB on an existing shared server. It's entirely up to the broker and the service provider that implements and runs the broker.

You would need to talk to the service provider and see if they are exposing service metrics like Postgres memory/CPU usage for the backing database they set up for each database they create on your behalf.